# Alternative for TableServiceContext.CreateQuery

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am using the method tableServiceContext.CreateQuery and now (After upgrading to Azure SDK 2.5) it says that *

> Support for accessing Windows Azure Tables via WCF Data Services is
>   now obsolete. It's recommended that you use the
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table namespace for working with
>   tables.

*

So can anyone suggest an alternative for this method in the *Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table* namespace. I am sharing the code below

```
 TableServiceContext tableServiceContext = this.tableClient.GetTableServiceContext();
            var query = (from e in this.tableServiceContext.CreateQuery<AuditLoggerEntity>(tableName)
                         where e.PartitionKey == organizationGuid && e.QueueMessageStatus != "Completed" && e.Action == "UpdateIdentityClaim"
                         select e).Take(resultsPerPage).AsTableServiceQuery<AuditLoggerEntity>(tableServiceContext);

            // Get the next continuation token
            var response = query.EndExecuteSegmented(query.BeginExecuteSegmented(nextToken, null, null));
```

The TableServiceContext class is also deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [`CloudTable.CreateQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn435361.aspx). Here's a sample code which makes use of it:

```
        var account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
        var tableClient = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
        var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("Address");
        var tableQuery = from e in table.CreateQuery<DynamicTableEntity>()
            where e.PartitionKey == "Address"
            select e;
        var queryResult = tableQuery.AsTableQuery().ExecuteSegmented(null).ToList();
```

Comment: What is the difference between query.EndExecuteSegmented(query.BeginExecuteSegmented(nextToken, null, null)); AND
tableQuery.AsTableQuery().ExecuteSegmented(null)

Comment: Begin/End is async implementation where as ExecuteSegmented is sync implementation. For async implementation, better alternative would be to use ExecuteSegmentedAsync

Comment: CreateQuery does not seem to be around any more and your link to the subject is 404'd.  Is there a new way to do this?

Comment: Looks like CreateQuery is not available in .Net Core (3 or earlier) https://stackoverflow.com/a/42942377/2589202